# Update multiple UILabels in custom UITableViewCell with data from multiple corresponding UITextFields? Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield, uilabel, uipickerview

I have a ViewController where a user can input their data in 4 UITextFields, populated by UIPickerViews, and when the user presses a save button the data is supposed to update the corresponding UILabels in the corresponding custom UITableViewCell.

See link below.

[TableView and Input ViewControllers with arrows showing corresponding UILabels and UITextFields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZqXr.jpg)

Currently, with the code provided, all UILabels in the custom UITableViewCell display the same data.

See link below.

[Current TableViewCell output in Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vTDR.jpg)

I suspect I'm having issues with either this part in the RunFeedViewController

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "runFeedCell1", for: indexPath) as! Mountain1TableViewCell
        cell.mountain1RunTypeLabel?.text = runFeedList[indexPath.item]
        cell.mountain1RunNameLabel?.text = runFeedList[indexPath.item]
        cell.mountain1RunSnowLabel?.text = runFeedList[indexPath.item]
        cell.mountain1RunDateLabel?.text = runFeedList[indexPath.item]

        return (cell)
}
```

and/or this part in the Mountain1RunInputViewController

```
@IBAction func saveMountain1Run(_ sender: Any) {
    if (mountain1RunDateTextField.text != "")
    {
        runFeedList.append(mountain1RunDateTextField.text!)
        mountain1RunDateTextField.text = ""
        UserDefaults.standard.set(runFeedList, forKey: "runFeedList")
    }

}
```

**What am I missing to make all 4 UILabels work with their corresponding UITextFields?**.

Here is the code for the RunFeedViewController with the UITableView.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase


var runFeedList = [String]()

class RunFeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var runFeedListTable: UITableView!

var ref: DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (runFeedList.count)
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "runFeedCell1", for: indexPath) as! Mountain1TableViewCell
        cell.mountain1RunTypeLabel?.text = runFeedList[indexPath.item]
        cell.mountain1RunNameLabel?.text = runFeedList[indexPath.item]
        cell.mountain1RunSnowLabel?.text = runFeedList[indexPath.item]
        cell.mountain1RunDateLabel?.text = runFeedList[indexPath.item]

        return (cell)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    {
        runFeedList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(runFeedList, forKey: "runFeedList")
        runFeedListTable.reloadData()
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    runFeedListTable.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "runFeedList") != nil
    {
        runFeedList = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "runFeedList") as! [String]
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func logOutAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUp")
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }
}
}
```

Here is the code for the Mountain1RunInputViewController where the user inputs the data in the 4 UITextFields.

```
import UIKit

var mountain1RunTypeArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

var mountain1RunNameArray1 = ["1A","1B","1C", "1D"]

var mountain1RunNameArray2 = ["2A","2B","2C", "2D"]

var mountain1RunNameArray3 = ["3A","3B","3C", "3D"]

var mountain1RunNameArray4 = ["4A","4B","4C", "4D"]

var mountain1RunSnowArray = ["Good", "Bad"]

var mountain1SelectedItemsArray = [String]()

var mountain1RunTypeTextField: String = ""
var mountain1RunNameTextField: String = ""
var mountain1RunSnowTextField: String = ""
var mountain1RunDateTextField: String = ""

class Mountain1RunInputViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate{


var pickerView1 = UIPickerView()
var pickerView2 = UIPickerView()
var pickerView3 = UIPickerView()
var pickerView4 = UIDatePicker()

@IBOutlet weak var mountain1RunTypeTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mountain1RunNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mountain1RunSnowTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mountain1RunDateTextField: UITextField!



@IBAction func saveMountain1Run(_ sender: Any) {
    if (mountain1RunDateTextField.text != "")
    {
        runFeedList.append(mountain1RunDateTextField.text!)
        mountain1RunDateTextField.text = ""
        UserDefaults.standard.set(runFeedList, forKey: "runFeedList")
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createToolbar()

    pickerView1 = UIPickerView()
    pickerView2 = UIPickerView()
    pickerView3 = UIPickerView()
    pickerView4 = UIDatePicker()

    pickerView1.delegate = self
    pickerView1.dataSource = self

    pickerView2.delegate = self
    pickerView2.dataSource = self

    pickerView3.delegate = self
    pickerView3.dataSource = self

    pickerView1.tag = 0
    pickerView2.tag = 1
    pickerView3.tag = 2
    pickerView4.tag = 3

    self.mountain1RunTypeTextField.inputView = self.pickerView1;
    self.mountain1RunNameTextField.inputView = self.pickerView2;
    self.mountain1RunSnowTextField.inputView = self.pickerView3;
    self.mountain1RunDateTextField.inputView = self.pickerView4;

    pickerView4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    pickerView4.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.dateAndTime
}

func createToolbar() {

    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(Mountain1RunInputViewController.cancelPicker1))
    let cancelButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(Mountain1RunInputViewController.cancelPicker2))
    let cancelButton3 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(Mountain1RunInputViewController.cancelPicker3))
    let cancelButton4 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(Mountain1RunInputViewController.cancelPicker4))

    // Tool bar for 1st UIPickerView

    let toolBar1 = UIToolbar()
    toolBar1.sizeToFit()
    toolBar1.barTintColor = .black
    toolBar1.tintColor = .white

    let doneButton1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(Mountain1RunInputViewController.doneButton1(sender:)))
    toolBar1.setItems([cancelButton1,spaceButton,doneButton1], animated: false)
    toolBar1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    mountain1RunTypeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar1

    // Tool bar for 2nd UIPickerView

    let toolBar2 = UIToolbar()
    toolBar2.sizeToFit()
    toolBar2.barTintColor = .black
    toolBar2.tintColor = .white

    let doneButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(Mountain1RunInputViewController.doneButton2(sender:)))
    toolBar2.setItems([cancelButton2,spaceButton,doneButton2], animated: false)
    toolBar2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    mountain1RunNameTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar2

    // Tool bar for 3rd UIPickerView

    let toolBar3 = UIToolbar()
    toolBar3.sizeToFit()
    toolBar3.barTintColor = .black
    toolBar3.tintColor = .white

    let doneButton3 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(Mountain1RunInputViewController.doneButton3(sender:)))
    toolBar3.setItems([cancelButton3,spaceButton,doneButton3], animated: false)
    toolBar3.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    mountain1RunSnowTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar3

    // Tool bar for UIDatePicker

    let toolBar4 = UIToolbar()
    toolBar4.sizeToFit()
    toolBar4.barTintColor = .black
    toolBar4.tintColor = .white

    let doneButton4 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(Mountain1RunInputViewController.doneButton4))
    toolBar4.setItems([cancelButton4,spaceButton,doneButton4], animated: false)
    toolBar4.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    mountain1RunDateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar4
}

func cancelPicker1(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func cancelPicker2(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func cancelPicker3(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func cancelPicker4(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

// Done button for 1st UIPickerView

func doneButton1(sender: AnyObject) {
    let row1 = pickerView1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0);
    pickerView(pickerView1, didSelectRow: row1, inComponent:0)
    view.endEditing(true)
}

// Done button for 2nd UIPickerView

func doneButton2(sender: AnyObject) {
    let row2 = pickerView2.selectedRow(inComponent: 0);
    pickerView(pickerView2, didSelectRow: row2, inComponent:0)
    view.endEditing(true)
}

// Done button for 3rd UIPickerView

func doneButton3(sender: AnyObject) {
    let row3 = pickerView3.selectedRow(inComponent: 0);
    pickerView(pickerView3, didSelectRow: row3, inComponent:0)
    view.endEditing(true)
}

// Done button for UIDatePicker

func doneButton4(){
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.long
    formatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    mountain1RunDateTextField.text = formatter.string(from: pickerView4.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}


func dismissKeyboard() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    pickerView4.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.dateAndTime
    mountain1RunDateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        return mountain1RunTypeArray.count
    } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return mountain1SelectedItemsArray.count
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        return mountain1RunSnowArray.count
    }
    return 1

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    if pickerView.tag == 0 {
        return mountain1RunTypeArray[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        return mountain1SelectedItemsArray[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        return mountain1RunSnowArray[row]
    }
    return ""
}

var selectedRow: Int = 0

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)  {

    selectedRow = row

    if pickerView == pickerView1 {
        mountain1RunTypeTextField.text = mountain1RunTypeArray[row]
        switch row {
        case 0:
            mountain1SelectedItemsArray = mountain1RunNameArray1;

        case 1:
            mountain1SelectedItemsArray = mountain1RunNameArray2
        case 2:
            mountain1SelectedItemsArray = mountain1RunNameArray3
        case 3:
            mountain1SelectedItemsArray = mountain1RunNameArray4

        default:
            mountain1SelectedItemsArray = []
        }
        pickerView2.reloadAllComponents()

    } else if pickerView == pickerView2 {
        let item = mountain1SelectedItemsArray[row]
        if mountain1SelectedItemsArray == mountain1RunNameArray1 {
            mountain1RunNameTextField.text = item
        } else if mountain1SelectedItemsArray == mountain1RunNameArray2 {
            mountain1RunNameTextField.text = item
        } else if mountain1SelectedItemsArray == mountain1RunNameArray3 {
            mountain1RunNameTextField.text = item
        } else if mountain1SelectedItemsArray == mountain1RunNameArray4 {
            mountain1RunNameTextField.text = item
        }
    }
    if pickerView.tag == 2 {
        mountain1RunSnowTextField.text = mountain1RunSnowArray[row]
    }
}

}
```

Here is the code for corresponding prototype cell.

```
import UIKit

class Mountain1TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var mountain1RunTypeLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mountain1RunNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mountain1RunSnowLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mountain1RunDateLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: How are you passing the runFeedList from RunInputViewController to RunFeedViewController ?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't find the way you are passing  runFeedList from RunInputViewController to RunFeedViewController ?
Could you please paste the code here

Comment: @AravindAR - I've added the full code for RunInputViewController. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I will try to update you with a solution for this

Comment: Hi Aravind AR. If you've got a spare minute can you look at the edits above and let me know if you can help out with my question.

Comment: All UILabels in the custom UITableViewCell is displaying the same data because you are assigning each of the label with the same data inside cellForRow at IndexPath

`cell.mountain1RunTypeLabel?.text = runFeedList[indexPath.item]
        cell.mountain1RunNameLabel?.text = runFeedList[indexPath.item]
        cell.mountain1RunSnowLabel?.text = runFeedList[indexPath.item]
        cell.mountain1RunDateLabel?.text = runFeedList[indexPath.item]`